# How can I pass a value to a service worker and then use it in a fetch event listener

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I need my service worker to monitor fetch requests and include a header value in the response if the request contains a certain path however this value isn't known until run time. I can use postMessage() to send the value and receive it in the sw's message listener, but then can't seem to use it in the fetch listener.

app.js

```
const customerUrl = "customerUrl.domain.com"  //this will come from a setting
const swr = new Worker('/sw.js')
swr.postMessage(customerUrl)
```

sw.js

```
let customerDomain = "foo.domain.com"

self.addEventListener("message", (msg) => {
  console.log("Service Worker Message Recieved", msg.data) // "customerUrl.domain.com"
  customerDomain = msg.data
  console.log(customerDomain) // "customerUrl.domain.com" ... awesome
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
  console.log("Fetch intercepted for " + customerDomain) // "foo.sample.com" but needs to be "customerUrl.domain.com"
  if (evt.url.includes("/bar/")) { 
    // ... modify request and send with customerDomain in header
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the `"Service Worker Message Recieved"` log?

Comment: Yes, along with the msg.data I need however the fetch event listener always shows the original foo.sample.com even after the message is received.  I may have found a way to do this using indexdb or by using a query parameter but was hoping for something more straight forward.

Comment: "*however the fetch event listener always shows the original foo.sample.com even after the message is received*" - it shouldn't. The closure (storing the `customerDomain` in the worker scope) approach works. Either you have fired the `fetch` too early, accidentally declared a local variable in the `message` handler, or are running multiple workers (and the one receiving the message is not the one that receives the fetch).

Comment: Thanks but none of those things were true. I believe it might be because the fetch event listener already gets loaded before the service worker receives the message post.
I was able to solve this by inserting the value I needed in a URL Parameter when registering the SW ... new Worker(/sw.js?customerDomain='customerUrl.domain.com'
 and then getting them in the fetch listener with
customerDomain = self.location.searchParams.get('customerDomain')